# boost::python - C++ calling Python calling C++

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have an application which will be extensible by Python code but the extensing code will also be using code from the application. Example of what I am trying to achieve:

// wrapped_module.cpp

```
void api_call()
{
 std::cout << "API call" << std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(API)
{
  boost::python::def("api_call", api_call);
}
```

// extension.py

```
import API

def myExtension()
 # ... some python work ... #
 API.api_call()
```

// application_main.cpp

```
int main()
{
 // initialize interpreter
 // load "extension.py"
 // make "API" module available for "extension.py", so "import API" works
 // load "myExtension" from "extension.py"
 // myExtension()
 // <see "API call" in console output>

 return 0;
}
```

"extension.py" will never be called as a standalone script, it will always be loaded by c++ application - therefore I do not need to separately build API.dll module for python to import - or do I?

Comment: https://github.com/TNG/boost-python-examples/blob/master/10-Embedding/embedding.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but not entirely straightforward.

You need to use an undocumented generated function name, in your case `initAPI` (it is composed from the word `init` and your module name, case-sensitive). You need to pass this function as an argument to `PyImport_AppendInittab` before calling `Py_Initialize`.

**Update** In Python 3, use `PyInit_API` instead if `initAPI`.

Below is a full working program that embeds Python and extends it with your module, then runs a simple program that uses your module.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void api_call()
{
     std::cout << "API call" << std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(API)
{
      boost::python::def("api_call", api_call);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Import your module to embedded Python
    PyImport_AppendInittab("API", &initAPI);

    // Initialise Python
    Py_Initialize();

    // Run Python code
    PyRun_SimpleString("import API\n"
                       "API.api_call()\n");

}
```

Comment: I saw couple examples which used PyImport_AppendInittab("something", &initSomething). I was trying hard to find where that mysterious initSomething() actualy is... you hit it. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to run this code, but getting an error saying  :
In function ‘int main()’:
full_flow.cpp:17:34: error: ‘initAPI’ was not declared in this scope
     PyImport_AppendInittab("API",initAPI);

any idea why this should happen ?

Comment: @BidishaDas In Python 3 it's called PyInit_API.